# how to read a message from hotmail/live delphi

Tags: delphi, hotmail, indy-9

In my application i am trying to read a new message that came to my hotmail account.

what is the best method to read email from hotmail/live.com  pop3 or IMAP ?

and can any one link some demo code of best method ?

regards

Comment: Is your question about connecting and downloading from HotMail/Live.com, or is it about handling the downloaded email in Delphi?

Comment: i want to read messages in hotmail/live

Comment: You did not answer Ken's question.  Do you want to know how to connect to Hotmail/Live's server, or do you want to know how to parse emails after connecting?  Those are two distinct issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdPOP3.html) ([simple zip example](http://downloads.atozed.com/indy/10/POP3Tool.zip), [connecting to gmail](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_4374.asp?SK) (should be same as hotmail)) or [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html?redirTo=/products/ics.html) components.

Comment: ICS has components for SSL as well as unencrypted TCP/IP. You have to get the OpenSSL DLLs that work with the components (OpenSSL 1.0 does NOT); those are on the ICS website as well.